# TypeError: dayjs(...).tz is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, dayjs

I am getting this error.

**TypeError: dayjs(...).tz is not a function**

My code is

const dayjs = require('dayjs');

const dayjsAmerica = dayjs("2014-06-01 12:00").tz("America/New_York");

Comment: You can tick `Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style` when posting this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extend the `dayjs` class with the `utc` and `timezone` classes/plugins:

```js
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
const utc = require('dayjs/plugin/utc');
const timezone = require('dayjs/plugin/timezone');
dayjs.extend(utc);
dayjs.extend(timezone);
```

Refer to docs for more details: https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/timezone

Answer (score 0):

this worked also for me as @kandula

```js
npm install dayjs

const dayjs = require('dayjs');

const utc = require('dayjs/plugin/utc');

const timezone = require('dayjs/plugin/timezone');

dayjs.extend(utc); dayjs.extend(timezone);
```